# Why can't I register any DLLs

Tags: windows-xp, dll

I run:

```
regsvr32 somefile.dll
```

There is a long delay (approx. 1 minute) and then a warning dialog pops up that says:

```
LoadLibrary("somefile.dll") failed.
GetLastError returns 0x0000007e.
```

The DLL is in my current directory.  I have tried multiple DLLs and they all give me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I had an old version of C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe.  I got a new version of the executable from one of the network admins and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238265 , about the 0x0000007e error code when registering a specific DLL

> This behavior occurs because the
>   Olemsg32.dll and Cdo.dll files are
>   being called from the wrong
>   installation point.

see if you can apply the fixes they suggest to your file, and you have to get administrative rights.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the DLL that I was trying to register required that an additional DLL (mvscrtd.dll) had to be present in the system32 directory.  I used the "Process Monitor" utility from Sysinternals to capture regsvr32 activity, and discovered a reference to the missing file.